# Gatsby static HTML build error when programatically creating pages with File System Route API curly braces

Tags: gatsby

I receive the following error when running `gatsby build` (`gatsby develop` works fine):

```
ERROR #95313 
Building static HTML failed for path "/services/blog-post-1/"
```

This is the structure of my site:

```
- pages
  - blog
   - {mdx.slug}.js
  - services
   - {mdx.slug}.js
```

It appears that gatsby is trying to build one of my blog post markdown files with my `/services/{mdx.slug}.js` template.

My gatsby-config.js looks like this:

```
    {
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
    name: `blog`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/services`,
    name: `services`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  ...
```

And these are the queries in each {mdx.slug}.js file:

Service:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ($id: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        author
      }
     }
    mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
      frontmatter {
        title
...
```

Blog post:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostById($id: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        author
      }
    }
    mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
      id
      excerpt(pruneLength: 160)
...
```

As I said, the site works fine using `gatsby develop` but `gatsby build` throws this error.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the queries of both files?

Comment: Updated @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 0):

Despite a lot of Googling, the only way I could resolve this issue was to revert to using [the Gatbsy Node API `createPages` extension](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/).

**How I did it:**

1. Moved my old {mdx.slug}.js files to `/src/templates/` and renamed them `service.js` and `blog-post.js` respectively.
2. Updated my `gatsby-node.js` file to [look like this](https://gist.github.com/dev-all-hands/68f54779f22cc501b7156729882edaa8)
3. Updated the queries in my `services` and `blog-post` template to:

   ```
   export const pageQuery = graphql`
   query BlogPostById($slug: String!) {
       site {
            siteMetadata {
       title
       author
     }
   }
   mdx(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
     excerpt(pruneLength: 160)
     body
     frontmatter {
       title
       date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
       description
       image {
         relativePath
         childImageSharp {
           gatsbyImageData(
             width: 1200
             height: 675 
             placeholder: BLURRED
           )
         }
       }
     }
   }`
   ```